# jQuery -- fadeIn image on hover, fadeOut after

Tags: html, jquery

I'm currently wrestling with an issue on a full screen menu I'm designing.

The menu has four items -- I'd like it such that for each menu item, an image fades in. If it's no longer hovering on that item, it can revert to the home image.

My HTML for the menu is as follows:

```
<div class = "menu">
  <div class = "images">
    <span class = "bg bg1 hide"></span>
    <span class = "bg bg2 hide"></span>
    <span class = "bg bg3 hide"></span>
    <span class = "bg bg4 hide"></span>
  </div>

  <div class = "nav">
    <div class = "menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span id = "order"> 01. </span>
          <span id = "menu"> &nbsp;Home /</span>
          <span id = "tag"> intro </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span id = "order"> 02. </span>
          <span id = "menu"> &nbsp;About /</span>
          <span id = "tag"> our history </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span id = "order"> 03. </span>
          <span id = "menu"> &nbsp;Careers /</span>
          <span id = "tag"> work here </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span id = "order"> 04. </span>
          <span id = "menu"> &nbsp;Contact /</span>
          <span id = "tag"> get in touch </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm then running the following jQuery script:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    $(".menu-item-1").hover(function() {
      $(".bg1").fadeIn(800);
    }, function() {
          $(".bg1").fadeOut(800);
    })
    $(".menu-item-2").hover(function() {
      $(".bg2").fadeIn(800);
    }, function() {
          $(".bg2").fadeOut(800);
    })
    $(".menu-item-3").hover(function() {
      $(".bg3").fadeIn(800);
    }, function() {
          $(".bg3").fadeOut(800);
    })
    $(".menu-item-4").hover(function() {
      $(".bg4").fadeIn(800);
    }, function() {
          $(".bg4").fadeOut(800);
    })
})
</script>
```

I'm at a bit of a loss on where to go from here -- really would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added class="menu-item-1" and data attribute to the li tags

https://api.jquery.com/data/

I commented all my javascript.

```js
jQuery(function() {
    // we find all animated span .bg
    var isAnimating = $(".bg").is(':animated');
    
    // we check if the span .bg are animated    
    if (!isAnimating) {
      // we get all hover event on li with class starting or like "menu-item-" 
      $("li[class^='menu-item-'],li[class*='menu-item-']").hover(function() {
        // we put in selector the value of data background
        $("." + $(this).attr("data-background")).fadeIn(800);
      }, function() {
        $("." + $(this).attr("data-background")).fadeOut(800);
      })
    }
})
```

```css
.bg { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "menu">
  <div class = "images">
    <span class = "bg bg1 hide">bg1</span>
    <span class = "bg bg2 hide">bg2</span>
    <span class = "bg bg3 hide">bg3</span>
    <span class = "bg bg4 hide">bg4</span>
  </div>

  <div class = "nav">
    <div class = "menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu-item-1" data-background="bg1">
          <span id = "order"> 01. </span>
          <span id = "menu"> &nbsp;Home /</span>
          <span id = "tag"> intro </span>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item-2" data-background="bg2">
          <span id = "order"> 02. </span>
          <span id = "menu"> &nbsp;About /</span>
          <span id = "tag"> our history </span>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item-3" data-background="bg3">
          <span id = "order"> 03. </span>
          <span id = "menu"> &nbsp;Careers /</span>
          <span id = "tag"> work here </span>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item-4" data-background="bg4">
          <span id = "order"> 04. </span>
          <span id = "menu"> &nbsp;Contact /</span>
          <span id = "tag"> get in touch </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've found that this works perfectly, so long as I haven't toggled .bg { display:none} in my stylesheet -- I'm not entirely sure why this is.